# C++ template which returns a different derived class based on template argument integer

Tags: c++, templates

I can't quite figure out the right pattern or idiom to do this, so I would appreciate suggestions.

Right now I have a pure virtual base class

```
template<typename T, int size>
class Base {

public:

    virtual Eigen::Matrix<T, x_size, 1>
    doSomething(const Eigen::Matrix<T, x_size, 1> &x) = 0;

    ...
```

and I have some derived classes with different values for the `size` template parameter. For instance,

```
template<typename T>
class Accelerometer : public Base<T, 4> { ...

template<typename T>
class Gyroscope : public Base<T, 5> { ...
```

There are many such classes. They are all quite different.

EDIT: I do not want to rename the classes, since doing to would make the code very confusing to read.

Elsewhere in the code, I have a class which holds a reference to a `Base` class object:

```
template<typename T, int size>
class Other {
private:

    Base<T, size> &base;

public:

    Other(Base<T, size> &base) : base(base) {...
```

So, for instance, I could say something like

```
Other<T, 4> other4( Derived4<T>() );
Other<T, 5> other5( Derived5<T>() );
```

However, in my main code, I only need one `Other` instance. Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
const int size = 4;
// TODO Initialize `other` with appropriate derived class. 
Other<T,size> other( getDerived<size>() )
```

where the `getDerived` function would return the `Derived` class of the appropriate size. I can't figure out how to define such a function. My first thought was to do something like this:

```
template<int size>
Base<size> getDerived() {
    return NULL;
}
```

However, that won't work because the Base class is a pure virtual. 
Next, I thought of perhaps doing some specialization of the template function

```
template<DerivedType>
DerivedType getDerived() {
    return NULL;
}
```

However, that is dumb because then I explicitly would have to state the class when calling the `getDerived` function.

So I feel like either I am missing something simple, or the entire approach I am using is wrong. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template partial specialization instead of hardcoding the number into the class `Derived4`, `Derived5`'s name:

```
template<class T, int N> struct Base {};

template<class T, int N> struct Derived;

template<class T>
struct Derived<T, 4> : public Base<T, 4> {
    /* for Derived4 */
};

template<class T>
struct Derived<T, 5> : public Base<T, 5> {
    /* for Derived5 */
};

template<class T, int N>
Derived<T, N> getDerived();
```

**EDIT:**

If you want class name to be descriptive, you can always use [`using` alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), for example:

```
template<class T> using Accelerometer = Derived<T, 4>;
template<class T> using Gyroscope = Derived<T, 5>;
```

Comment: I see. That would work from a syntax point of view, but that would really screw up the naming

Comment: The Derived classes are each very long. They pertain to different sensor types

Comment: E.g. Accelerometer, Gyroscope, etc.

Comment: So doing it this way would make the code very confusing to read. I COULD put some comments in, but I really think it is much cleaner to have the the class name be descriptive. I will add this to the question.

Comment: As originally stated, you do present a valid approach though.

Comment: @bremen_matt If your class has very long name, it would be even better to put some of them to template list. For me, if something is related to a template parameter, I will never hardcode it into name. Maybe I can't get your point.

Comment: I am not saying that the names are long. I mean the individual classes represented quite a lot of code. I think it would be very odd to toss away the descriptive class names "Accelerometer" and "Gyroscope" in favor of "Sensor<T, 4>" and "Sensor<T, 5>"

Comment: @bremen_matt If this is what prevents you from template specialization, I think `using` alias will help. `template<class T> using Accelerometer = Sensor<T, 4>;`

Comment: @bremen_matt You can always use `template alias` and do something like `using Gyroscope = Sensor<T, 5>`

Comment: @bremen_matt Updated.